# Interpolated data not working

Tags: angular, typescript

Somethings wrong with my code, I am trying to implement shariff which is a privacy sharing module.

I have tried these and both don't work:

```
[attr.data-url]="text"

attr.data-url="{{text}}"
```

I am attempting to bind the current url data to the shariff tag, but it resolves before the ngOnit tag finishes going through the observable, resulting in the url to be just "https://client.wildfyre.net/", when it should be "https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/**AREA**/**ID**" I am not sure what I can do to fix the problem

home.comp.html

```
<div class="shariff" data-lang="en" data-orientation="vertical" data-services="[&quot;facebook&quot;,&quot;googleplus&quot;,&quot;twitter&quot;]" data-theme="white" data-title="WildFyre" [attr.data-url]=text></div>
```

home.comp.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Post, Area, Reputation } from '../_models';
    import { PostService, AreaService } from '../_services';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      post: Post;
      rep: Reputation;
      model: any = {};
      color = 'warn';
      checked: boolean;
      isCopied = false;
      text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net/';

      constructor(
        private postService: PostService,
        private areaService: AreaService
      ) {
        this.checked = this.areaService.isAreaChecked;

        this.areaService.getAreaRep(this.areaService.currentAreaName)
          .subscribe(reputation => {
            this.rep = reputation;
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        document.getElementById('navB').style.display = '';

        this.postService.getNextPost(this.areaService.currentAreaName)
          .subscribe((post: Post) => {
            this.post = post;
            this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName + '/' + post.id;
          });
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the current behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Current behavior outputs just "client.wildfyre.net" when it should be "client.wildfyre.net/areas/AREA/ID"

This is set in ngonit
But for some reason it doesn't update the attr in the shariff tag, and the shariff tag uses the originally set URL

Comment: What does get printed when you add `console.log(this.text)` after the line `this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre...`?

Comment: You have about 50 lines of code in the question which are entirely unrelated to the question. This makes it quite difficult to find out what is relevant to the question and what not.

Comment: The correct URL is displayed for console.log(this.text)

Comment: https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/fun/184197939 -The output

Comment: Edited OP to make it easier to see my problem

Comment: Looks like an issue with `postService` or other code of yours that calls `ngOnInit()` or causes `ngOnit()` to be called.

Comment: That's a **lot** better :)

Comment: Try to add `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` to the constructor parameters and add `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` directly after `this.text = 'https://client.wild...`

Comment: ngonit is only ran once, unless the user does an action, however the shariff tag implements no function, rather a variable

Comment: Console.log still correct, changeref did nothing

Comment: You previously had `{{text}}` in the HTML. What does this show?

Comment: Should I turn the variable into an observable and just wait for it?

Comment: {{text}} shows the correct URL, only after it has been updated, my guess is that when the app initializes it hard sets that attr and won't let it change

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. It might make sense though, but it's not the cause of the issue.

Comment: So what exactly is now the problem? I'm sure if you check the DOM `data-url` will have the correct value as well.

Comment: The correct URL is set in dom, however when I click on a share button it does this: http://prntscr.com/g4cdsu

Comment: I guess that the widget you're using just doesn't recognize that the attribute has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not an Angular issue but an issue of the non-Angular widget you're using that depends on the `data-url` attribute.

Try

```
#shariff [attr.data-url]="text"
```

```
@ViewChild('shariff') shariff:ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
   ...

   this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName + '/' + post.id;
   new Shariff(shariff.nativeElement, {
     orientation: 'vertical'
   });
```

Comment: <div *ngIf="showText" class="shariff" data-lang="en" data-orientation="vertical" data-services="[&quot;facebook&quot;,&quot;googleplus&quot;,&quot;twitter&quot;]" data-theme="grey" data-title="WildFyre" [attr.data-url]=text></div>

|||||||||||Did this and this:||||||||||||||||||
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName + '/' + post.id;
        this.showText = true;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.text)

Comment: @CameronGilbert try *ngIf="text" showText is never defined so the ngIf always results to false (causing the div to not render)

Comment: Didn't add that to my comment because I thought that would be inferred:
Set like this before constructor:   showText: boolean = false;
still not working, changed to ngIf="text" , displays, but original problem is back

Comment: Sorry, I had a slightly different approach in mind at first and then forgot to change the `ngIf`. I didn't dive into how to use the shariff widget, but I guess you need to call the JS function again to initialize it, every time after the element was re-added to the DOM (after the code in my answer).

Comment: Would you know how to proceed?

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't plan to dig further into shariff though.

Comment: Then I don't know :-/